# Emacs RTags: rtags-find-references-at-point

Tags: plugins, emacs, code-navigation, rtags

I just installed RTags with Emacs but I am a bit frustrated because while using
"rtags-find-references-at-point", Emacs open another window with the different references but do not focus on it. Meaning, each time I am using this functionality, I have to manually switch to that window. It is a normal behavior ? Or is there a way to overcome this "issue" ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally decided to use the following function:

```
(defun rtags-find-references-at-point-focus ()
  (when (rtags-find-references-at-point)
  (select-window (first (get-buffer-window-list "*RTags*")))))
```

Answer (score 1):

I found it quite easy to use `next-error` and `previous-error` functions: global bindings `M-g n` and `M-g p` by default.

This will jump between different matches while keeping the focus in the current window.

The problem I'm trying to solve now is a pretty random window split every time.